# Profile picture (Portrait) validation in web services

Tags: python, image-processing, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing a service which can validate input picture either it is suitable portrait (Profile picture) or not.
If possible service can return scoring. Each consumer can set required accepted criteria.

Some key rules I want to implement for image validation are

- Background of image is not busy
- Person face is recognizable i.e. ears, nose, eyes, mouth are visible
- Only one person is identified in picture

I am new to image processing. I ll prefer if I can find some source in .Net core. I can also choose python

Comment: so you want ready-made software? that's asking for recommendations. please review [help/on-topic]

Comment: I mentioned that I want to build Web services, either in Net core or Python. Which provide me better result

Comment: Your needs should be specific to your business, and you can match your needs with the returned data after face recognition.

Answer (score 0):

This issue related to face Recognition.

If you don't want to use [the cognitive-services from Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/cognitive-services/face/) or other providers. You can check the [FaceRecognitionDotNet](https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/FaceRecognitionDotNet).

And here is [the sample](https://github.com/fmarencic/foiEPP)(asp.net core), you can check it.

---

If you face the error below, please search it via google, and there are a lot of github issues.

```
---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DlibDotNet.NativeMethods' threw an exception.
---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'DlibDotNetNativeDnn' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.
```